# WiFi is not working with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on an Acer TravelMate 5520

Tags: 14.04, wireless

Wired connection works. 
Ran: `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`, then restarted - still no wifi.

```
paul@paul-TravelMate-5520:~$ lspci -nn | grep 0280 
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `linux-firmware-nonfree` doesn't correctly install the required firmware. The correct method is:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Please see: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395)

Comment: Those commands did not work after restart. Still no WIFI. I have tried an install of LinuxMint. Runs a bit faster on this old hardware. Can I try the same commands?

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Can I try the same commands in Mint?

Comment: Certainly. Should work perfectly.

Comment: This solution worked. Much Appreciated.